# Scanf parsing a string

Tags: c, parsing, scanf, delimiter

i'm trying to develop a method that parses a file where each element is separated  by a comma.

I am trying to figure out a way to use `scanf` to delimit the elements. I tried using `scanf("%[^,]",buffer)` but got a stack smashing error.

Also do not refer me to other articles I've tried them all. Please let me know how I can use my `scanf` as a delimiter.

My input is as follows:

```
+,-,*,/,%,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,0123456789,(,),;,=, \t\n
```

Below is the code

```
       char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
for (int i = 0; i < returnTable->numberOfClasses-1; i++) {
    scanf("%s ",buffer);
    buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
    returnTable->inputSymbolClasses[i] = malloc((sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer) )+ 1));
    strcpy(returnTable->inputSymbolClasses[i],buffer);
}
```

Comment: regarding: `returnTable->inputSymbolClasses[i] = malloc((sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer) )+ 1));`  The expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and the expression is just cluttering the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s ",buffer);`  this will stop scanning when any 'white space' is encountered, so will not input the whole line

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out for anyone struggling with this, use `scanf("%[^,],",buffer)` to delimit by commas.